# Writing a more concise OR condition with Python

Tags: python

I have a set of paths I'd like to check before append it to a list.
Is there a functional way to write this such that the conditional statement is less redundant?

```
if not path.endswith(".json") or not path.endswith(".toc") or not path.endswith("_index") or not path.endswith(...) or ...:
    some_list.append(path)
```

Comment: [`str.endswith` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) also accepts a `tuple` of suffices, so you can do `path.endswith(('.toc', '_index', ...)`

Comment: Also, with `not` having higher priority than `or`, all this test is checking is that the string does not end with `.json`. I wonder if `not path.endswith(suffixes)` was the intended function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) supports a tuple of different endings:

```
if not path.endswith(".json") or path.endswith((".toc", "_index", ...)):
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `any()` to iterate over a list of possible options

```
accepted = [".toc", "_index"] 
if not path.endswith(".json") or any(path.endswith(x) for x in accepted):
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
file_exts = ['.json', '.toc', '_index']

if not any(path.endswith(ext) for ext in file_exts)):
    some_list.append(path)
```

Comment: This isn't the same logic. The `not` isn't applied over every element in the question

Comment: While that is true, the question's condition is probably not what was intended, as the first test renders the rest moot.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ya, realized I misread the question afterwards. Though based on the OP's title wording, I think it was implied he wanted to check for negation on all endings.